# cargar datos desde ajax a datalist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5, ajax

hola quiero traer desde mi base de datos una lista pero ya me la trae lo que pasa es que no me la muestra y de verdad no se que hacer ya un ayudita me viniera bien.

```js
function filtro() {
  // var valor = document.getElementById("destinatario").value;
  var valor = 'ke';
  if (valor.length > 0) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      dataType: 'text',
      url: "filtrodestinatario.htm",
      data: {
        'email': valor
      },
      success: function(response) {
        var z = JSON.parse(response);

        var opcion = "<option value='" + z[0][0] + "'>" + z[0][0] + "</option>";
        //var opcion="<label>"+z[0][0]+"</label>";

        var todo = opcion;
        alert(todo);
        $("#usu").append(todo);
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('Error: ');
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' placeholder='Ingrese Usuario' class='flexdatalist' 
data-min-length='1' multiple='' data-selection-required='1' list='languages' 
id="destinatario" name='destinatario' onkeypress="filtro()">

<datalist id='languages'>
 <!-- <option value="kevin">jose</option>-->
                                                 <div id="usu"></div> 
                                            </datalist>
```

Comment: el elemento "usu" es un DIV no es un SELECT

Comment: el archivo que te da la respuesta es de extension php?

Comment: Hay dos problemas: 1. El elemento al cual debes añadir las opciones es `#languages`. 2. Asegúrate de usar un polyfill para datalist; no tiene soporte de todos los navegadores.

Comment: ya lo hecho así si carga pero no me lo muestra en la vista @GustavoGarcía

Comment: Debería. Si no te muestra nada quizás se deba a que `z` tenga datos vacíos. Inspecciona el datalist y mira si tiene elementos `option` dentro. Otra cosa, en los datalist, los option no deben tener etiqueta de cierre.

Comment: por lo que entriendo es asi? "<option value='"+z[0][0]+"'>"+z[0][0]+">", otra cosa cuado inspecciono el elemto si cargan los datos el problema es que los muestre en el datalist @GustavoGarcía

Comment: Lo correcto es: `"<option value=" + z[0][0] + "/>"`. Fíjate en [este fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kzk64j2w/).

Comment: ya lo probé pero igual no me lo muestra en la vista, no se si sea algún script que de pronto me este bloqueando el datalist @GustavoGarcía

Comment: Todo indica que no está trayendo registros. ¿Ya viste la respuesta que te retorna la API? Haz `console.dir(z)`.

Comment: si el me muestra esto <option value="kevin">kevin</option> mas no me lo muestra en la vista del datalist. @GustavoGarcía

Comment: La verdad no veo que más pueda ser. Como pudiste ver en el código que pasé por enlace, haciendo lo mismo que tú, funciona. ¿Al menos te renderiza el componente?

Comment: si @GustavoGarcía

Comment: ya me funciono es el css del j-query gracias @GustavoGarcía

Comment: Me alegro. Si consideras que tu pregunta debe ser eliminada, hazlo. Si no, coloca la respuesta para que la aceptes.